# Changing JPanels after clicking Jbutton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, cardlayout

There are 2 JPanels in my code. The first one is Furutsu7 which is the main JPanel which includes my game. The second JPanel is the start Jbutton. What I'm trying to accomplish is after the user clicks the Jbutton, the Furutsu7 JPanel will appear.

This is my setup class where I created the buttons.

```
public void setup(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Start ");
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();


    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

    JButton Card1Button = new JButton("Start");
    card1.add(Card1Button);
    JButton Card2Button = new JButton("Exit");
    card2.add(Card2Button);

    cards.add(card1, "C1");
    cards.add(card2, "C2");

    f.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    f.setTitle("Furutsu");
    f.setSize(500, 300);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);



 }
```

What I need help on is what should I put in my action performed in order to switch to the Furutsu JPanel.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


}
```

Comment: crossposted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/664974/GUI/java/Changing-Panels-clicking-JButton

Answer (score 5):

Make your CardLayout a field of the class so that you can more easily get to it in your actionPerformed method. Otherwise you would need to call `(CardLayout) cards.getLayout()`, a riskier thing to do. For example:

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel cards = new JPanel(cardLayout);

    public void setup(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Start ");
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();

        // cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        JButton Card1Button = new JButton("Start");
        card1.add(Card1Button);
        JButton Card2Button = new JButton("Exit");
        card2.add(Card2Button);

        cards.add(card1, "C1");
        cards.add(card2, "C2");

        f.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setTitle("Furutsu");
        f.setSize(500, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Then you can directly refer to it:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // now you can call methods on your cardLayout variable:
    cardLayout.show(...);  // I'll leave it to you to figure out what to put in here
}
```

For more on CardLayout, please check out its [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Note that if you just want to swap components in forward or backwards order, look at the other methods of CardLayout, such as `next(cards)` and `previous(cards)`